# For fat, full-rank matrix $A$, why does $I - A^T(AA^T)^{-1}A$ give projection onto $\mathcal{N}(A)$?

Tags: least-squares

Suppose we are trying to solve the least-norm problem for underdetermined equations, i.e. we want to minimize $\|x\|$ given that $Ax = y$ with $A \in \mathbf{R}^{m \times n}$ and $m < n$. I know that (and can prove) the least-norm solution is given by $x_{\textrm{ln}} = A^\dagger y$, and I also have some intuition about the idea that $x_{\textrm{ln}}$ is the projection of $0 \in \mathcal{N}(A)$ onto $\{ x \mid Ax = y \}$.

However, I can't figure out why $I - A^T(AA^T)^{-1}A$ gives projection onto $\mathcal{N}(A)$.

In the analogous least-squares (over constrained) case, we have that $AA^\dagger y = Ax_{\textrm{ls}}$ and it's clear to me that $AA^\dagger$ then will give the projection of $y$ onto $\mathcal{R}(A)$. I have a feeling I'm being confused by some subtle difference in the nature of the projections between the overconstrained and underconstrained cases.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1294685/orthogonal-projection-matrix

Answer (score 2):

Given the linear system
$$
\mathbf{A} x = y,
$$
the least squares solution is defined as
$$
  x_{LS} = \left\{
  x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \colon
\lVert 
  \mathbf{A} x - y
\rVert_{2}^{2}
\text{ is minimized}
\right\}
$$
Please note that the length $\lVert x \rVert$ is not minimized here. It is the difference between data and prediction $\lVert \mathbf{A}x-y \rVert$ which is minimized.

The general least squares solution is 
$$
 x_{LS} = 
\color{blue}{\mathbf{A}^{+}b} + 
\color{red}{\left( \mathbf{I}_{n} - \mathbf{A}^{+}\mathbf{A} \right) z}, \quad z \in \mathbf{R}^{n}
$$
Because you have stipulated an underdetermined problem where $m<n$, the solution will not be unique. The affine space of least squares minimizers is represented by the red dashed line in the figure below.

[image: domain]

The solution vector of least length is the vector which lies within the column space, $\color{blue}{\mathbf{A}^{+}b}$.

You ask about the projector matrix
$$
\color{red}{\mathbf{P}_{\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{A})}} = 
\color{red}{\left( \mathbf{I}_{n} - \mathbf{A}^{+}\mathbf{A} \right)} =
\color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}} \mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}^{*}}
$$
which assume the singular value decomposition
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A} &=
  \mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{*} \\
%
 &=
% U 
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} & \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right]  
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cccccc}
     \sigma_{1} & 0 & \dots &  &   & \dots &  0 \\
     0 & \sigma_{2}  \\
     \vdots && \ddots \\
       & & & \sigma_{\rho} \\
       & & & & 0 & \\
     \vdots &&&&&\ddots \\
     0 & & &   &   &  & 0 \\
  \end{array} \right]
% V 
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\ 
     \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array} \right]  \\
%
  & =
% U
   \left[ \begin{array}{cccccccc}
    \color{blue}{u_{1}} & \dots & \color{blue}{u_{\rho}} & \color{red}{u_{\rho+1}} & \dots & \color{red}{u_{n}}
  \end{array} \right]
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \mathbf{S}_{\rho\times \rho} & \mathbf{0} \\
     \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
  \end{array} \right]
% V
   \left[ \begin{array}{c}
    \color{blue}{v_{1}^{*}} \\ 
    \vdots \\
    \color{blue}{v_{\rho}^{*}} \\
    \color{red}{v_{\rho+1}^{*}} \\
    \vdots \\ 
    \color{red}{v_{n}^{*}}
  \end{array} \right]
%
\end{align}
$$
Constructing the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse 
$$
 \mathbf{A}^{+} = 
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}} & \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right]  
%
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \mathbf{S}^{-1} & \mathbf{0} \\
     \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
  \end{array} \right]
%
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}^{*}_{\mathcal{R}}} \\ \color{red}{\mathbf{U}^{*}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right]  
$$
leads to
$$
\mathbf{A}^{+} \mathbf{A} =   
%
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}} & \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right]  
%
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \mathbf{I}_{\rho} & \mathbf{0} \\
     \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
  \end{array} \right]
%
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}^{*}_{\mathcal{R}}} \\ \color{red}{\mathbf{V}^{*}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right]  
$$
You can see how the central matrix product acts like a stencil, removing all range space components.